# Square Connect API | Generate Personal Access Token via API

Tags: php, wordpress, square-connect, square

I am using Personal Access Token from my Square Dashboard to Create Payments using the Square Connect PHP SDK.

Everything is going fine and now I read somewhere in documentation that Access Tokens expire every 30 days. So that means payments on my website will stop working after 30 days? Because I can not find any API to obtain fresh personal access token. And I don't want to manually plug in access token every 30 days.

```
        $api_config = new \SquareConnect\Configuration();
        $api_config->setHost($host_url);
        $api_config->setAccessToken($access_token);
        $api_client = new \SquareConnect\ApiClient($api_config);        
        $payments_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\PaymentsApi($api_client);

        $request_body = array (
        "source_id" =>$data['nonce'],
        "amount_money" => array (
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => $currency
        ),
        "shipping_address" => array (
            "address_line_1" => $data['address_1'],
            "address_line_2" => $data['address_2'],
            "postal_code" => $data['postal_code'],
            "country" => $data['country'],
            "first_name"  => $data['first_name'],
            "last_name" => $data['last_name'],
        ),
        "customer_id" => $transaction->user_id,
        "buyer_email_address" => $data['email'],
        "reference_id" => $transaction->id,
        "note" => $note,
        "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
        );
```

P.S: Square API documentation is the most shitty documentation ever!!!

Comment: If you think Square's documentation is bad, something tells me you haven't read a whole lot of documentation in your day.  This is actually some of the better written documentation I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal Access Tokens never expire. If you use [OAuth](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/what-it-does), then the access tokens do expire every 30 days, and you would use the [ObtainToken](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/oauth#endpoint-oauth-obtaintoken) with a `refresh_token` in order to generate a new access token.

Furthermore, feel free to send your feedback about our documentation to Square's [Developer Support](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68) team so we can make it better.

Comment: so it can be used indefinitely without the need for replacing? And is it safe to use Personal Access tokens?

Comment: On the following link:

[link]https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/oauth#endpoint-oauth-renewtoken[link]

It says: **OAuth access tokens besides your application's personal access token expire after 30 days.**
This got me confused because this means Personal Access Tokens expire too.

Comment: "besides" means personal access token is not included in the rest of the statement. You can use it forever without replacing. It's technically safe, yes, although we do typically recommend using an OAuth token just to limit the scope of permissions. Ultimately, there will be no harm done by using the personal access token, though.

Comment: Alright thank you sir.
I guess I need to work on my English then :D